# API's need every page of my site listed in restrictions

Tags: google-maps

my site is under development and is designed to help victims of our current massive flood disaster here in Australia
the site is at https://ineedhelp-nr.com.au/ - front end password = helpme 
The issue I am having is with the Google maps API - I have added the cover all domain of (asterix).ineedhelp-nr.com.au/(asterix) but I still seem to have to enter every single page that uses the map into the website restrictions 
its tricky because I need to add

"ineedhelp-nr.com.au/add-directory-listing?bundle=directory_listing"

as wells as

"ineedhelp-nr.com.au/add-directory-listing/"

there may be calls I am not aware of that will load pages with the map not working
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`*.ineedhelp-nr.com.au/*` covers all *sub-domains* of `ineedhelp-nr.com.au`, but not pages on the main domain itself (it doesn't match `ineedhelp-nr.com.au/add-directory-listing/`).

To match `ineedhelp-nr.com.au/add-directory-listing/` use: `ineedhelp-nr.com.au/*` (without the `*.`)

If you do have sub-domains, these 2 rules should work:

```
*.ineedhelp-nr.com.au/*
ineedhelp-nr.com.au/*
```

Comment: Thanks - but I have both those in the restrictions section URL's - still the maps don't work in some pages

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message on the page that doesn't work?